Qualtrics: Pipe largest value of a multiple choice question which allows more than one response
I have a multiple choice question that is simply this:

Which of the following years did you participate (select all that apply)?
2019
2020
2021
2022
2023

A later question asks:

Relative to ${e://Field/largestYear}, how would you rate the following?

So clearly, I want only the highest selected year in the prior question to be piped into the second question as largestYear.
This is the jscript attached to the first question:
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    // Wait until the respondent has interacted with the question
    this.questionclick = function(event, element) {
        // Initialize max value
        var max = 2019;
        // Loop through selected choices
        jQuery("#"+this.questionId+" .ChoiceStructure tbody tr").each(function() {
            // Check if choice is selected
            if (jQuery(this).find(".Selected").length > 0) {
                // Retrieve numerical value of choice
                var value = parseFloat(jQuery(this).find("td:first").text());
                // Update max value if necessary
                if (value > max) {
                    max = value;
                }
            }
        });
        // Set the embedded data with the largest value
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('largestYear', max);
    }
});

The resulting imbedded data in question two always turns out to be equal to the assignment in the jscript line var max = 2019 no matter what (numeric) value I put into that statement. I have no experience coding java and have no experiencing debugging under Qualtrics, but I assume the line var value = parseFloat(jQuery(this).find("td:first").text()) is the problem. So I tried to recode the responses, so that it is a numbered list from 1 to 5, and that did not work, and I tried variable naming - figured, what the heck? It can't hurt at this point.
I'm hoping someone here has some thoughts on what I'm doing wrong. I tried asking this on Qualtrics Community, but it seems to have locked me out for too many log in attempts.
Any thoughts will be appreciated.
Steve

I eventually got this question posted on the Qualtrics user group, where a poster suggested the following code that was able to accomplish this task based on the ordering of the choices - from earlier to later years:
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    this.questionclick = function(event, element) {
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('RecentYear', this.getQuestionInfo().Choices[this.getSelectedChoices().last()].Text);
    }
});


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
